# I want to update next textbox based on upper selected dropdown list in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

## This is my Dropdown list:

```
$fieldset->addField('auto_play','select',
array('label'=>Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Auto Play'),
    'values'=>Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
    'name'=>'auto_play',
    'value'=> $config['auto_play']));
```

**Now i wants to add below textbox based on upper selected value**

```
$fieldset->addField('delay', 'text',
                array('label'=> Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Delay Speed'),
              'after_element_html'=>'<small>Work only if Auto play is set to "Yes"</small>',
              'name'=>'delay','value'=> $config['delay']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like below

```
   $fldSet4->addField('include_flag', 'select', array(
          'label'     => $hlp->__('Include Only Selected Categories'),
          'name'      => 'include_flag',
          'values'    => $yesno
        )); 

// drop down if yes then show below text box

        $fldSet4->addField('include_only', 'text', array(
          'label'     => $hlp->__('Include Only Categories'),
          'name'      => 'include_only',
          'note'      => $hlp->__('Comma separated list of the categories IDs like 17,4,25'),
        ));


        // Append dependency javascript

        $this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('include_flag', 'include_flag')
        ->addFieldMap('include_only', 'include_only')
        ->addFieldDependence('include_only', 'include_flag', 1) // 2 = 'Specified'
);
```

**EDIT**

```
   $this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap('auto_play', 'auto_play')
            ->addFieldMap('delay', 'delay')
            ->addFieldDependence('delay', 'auto_play', 1) // 2 = 'Specified'
    );
```

Change 3rd argument of `->addFieldDependence` function as you need.

try to understand it carefully.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Can you describe in my code, b'use i am new in this

Comment: @ParagDave, use my edited answer to achieve ur solution.

Comment: hi liyakat, how can i do for same in radio button case? i have 5 value in radio button. how can i apply for this same hide/unhide button?